# Proving periodicity of an arbitrary function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

I could not think of a proof to probably trivial question:
Let $y=f(x)$ be a periodic function on any closed interval $a\le{x}\le{a+T}$, if T is a period of the function $f(x)$, then the numbers $2T, 3T, 4T,...$ are also periods. Prove validity of
$f(x)=f(x+T)=f(x+2T)=f(x+3T)=\cdots$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Thank you. I could not think of a way to begin proof thus could not make a try. I would welcome hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove by induction that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f(x+nT)=f(x)$.